# In a matrix of characters, find a particular String

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a matrix of characters, suppose 4*5 matrix

> A-C-P-**F**
>
> X-S–**O**-P
>
> V-**U**-Q-N
>
> W-G-**N**–M
>
> **D**-A-T-I

I want to find whether word **FOUND** is present in that matrix.

My matrix is given below (JAVA code)

```
char matrixOfChars[][]={
{'A','C','P','F'},
{'X','S','O','P'},
{'V','U','Q','N'},
{'W','G','N','M'},
{'D','A','T','I'}};
```

*Note : in matrix , first word is always in first row , second word always in second row and so on*

Code done so far for single string is below

```
private static void generateCombinations(String original, String combination) {
        if (original.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(combination);
        } else {
            for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++){
                generateCombinations(original.substring(0,i) + original.substring(i+1,original.length()),combination + original.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me to find out solution for above in JAVA . It will be better if solution is given using java recursion.

Thank you.

Comment: 1k+ rep and still posting questions without showing any effort.... Disappointing!

Comment: @OomphFortuity check the answer, did it using recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over FOUND's chars with a loop, use `Arrays.asList` and `indexOf` in each row of your matrix to get position and make a new array or what you need

```
String word = "FOUND";
int[] sollution = new int[work.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    int index = Arrays.asList(matrixOfChars[i]).indexOf(word.charAt(i));
    System.out.print(index + "\n");       
    sollution[i] = index;
}

Arrays.toString(sollution);
```

You will get this output:

```
 3
 2
 1
 2
 0
```

And `sollution = {3 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    char matrixOfChars[][]={
            {'A','C','P','F'},
            {'X','S','O','P'},
            {'V','U','Q','N'},
            {'W','G','N','M'},
            {'D','A','T','I'}};

    System.out.println(find(matrixOfChars,5,4, "FOUND"));
}

public static boolean find(char matrixOfChars[][],int rowsSize,int columnSize,String word)
{
    if(word.length()!=rowsSize)
        return false;
    String temp="";
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columnSize; j++) {
            if(word.charAt(i)==matrixOfChars[i][j])
            {
                temp+=word.charAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    if(temp.equals(word))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

recursive solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char matrixOfChars[][] = { { 'A', 'C', 'P', 'F' },
            { 'X', 'S', 'O', 'P' }, { 'V', 'U', 'Q', 'N' },
            { 'W', 'G', 'N', 'M' }, { 'D', 'A', 'T', 'I' } };
    String word="AGUNC";
    String res=find2(matrixOfChars, 5, 4, word);
    System.out.println(res);
    System.out.println(res.equals(word));

}

static String temp = "";
static int n = 0;

public static String find2(char matrixOfChars[][], int rowsSize,
        int columnSize, String word) {

    if (word.length() != rowsSize || n == rowsSize)
        return temp;
    else {

        for (int j = 0; j < columnSize; j++) {
            if (word.charAt(n) == matrixOfChars[n][j]) {
                temp += word.charAt(n);
                n++;
                return find2(matrixOfChars, rowsSize, columnSize, word);
            }

        }
        n++;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using recursion :**

```
class Test {

    static char matrixOfChars[][]={
            {'A','C','P','F'},
            {'X','S','O','P'},
            {'V','U','Q','N'},
            {'W','G','N','M'},
            {'D','A','T','I'}};

    static int n = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        n = matrixOfChars.length - 1;
        find();
    }

    public static void find() {
        String word = "";

        if(n >= 0) {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < matrixOfChars[n].length ; i ++) {
                word += matrixOfChars[n][i];
            }

            if(word.equals("FOUND")) {
                System.out.println("FOUND is found");

            } else {

                n--;
                find();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("FOUND is not found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: code is not working,please check.It is giving not found result

Comment: @OomphFortuity, the result is not found because, there is now `{'F', 'O', 'U', 'N', 'D'}` in that array.

Did you mean anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
    char matrixOfChars[][]={
    {'A','C','P','F'},
    {'X','S','O','P'},
    {'V','U','Q','N'},
    {'W','G','N','M'},
    {'D','A','T','I'}};

    String word = "FOUND";
    int[] sol = new int[word.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

        char y = word.charAt( i );
        int z = new String( matrixOfChars[i] ).indexOf( y );

        System.out.print( z + "\n" );
        sol[i] = z;
    }

    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( sol ) );
```